# Net is not working inside my android program

Tags: android, eclipse, browser, webview

I made a simple web browser with WebView, and I set it to load google, but it's like it doesn't even know there is some Wifi connection on my phone. without even trying to load it says "Webpage not available".
It doesn't even load "192.168.1.1" which is modem configuration.
My question is should I use any special code for it to be able to use my wifi or not? (my wifi is already connected and works with Firefox or Chrome)

Tnx.

Edit: Here's the whole code of the program, not much.

```
import java.net.NetPermission;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);    
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("192.168.1.1");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code so we can better help you with your problem?

Comment: Try adding _http://_ or _https://_ before any URL you are trying to load.

Comment: that doesn't work. Before this it was "https ://www.google.com"(without space) and still wasn't working

Comment: I said, it acts like there is not even internet connection in my phone.

Comment: Have you added the Internet permission in your Manifest?

Comment: No, can you help me with that? I'm new in android.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Just include the `uses-permission` line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you require the Internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <!-- Activities go here -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```